# Finding a player with a certain item and giving them another item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a current map and this is the only hitch I'm at so far. I know that I can do a testfor command with a command block to see if anyone is holding a specific item, but I also want to give the person that has that item on them, a new item. For example, if someone has a diamond on them, I want to be able to, through command blocks, find that person and give them a blaze rod. Appreciate all help!

Comment: Do you want this to be like an exchange? Like, taking away the diamond block and replacing it? Or just a one-time thing that doesn't take that item away?

Comment: I dont want it to take the item away, just identify that it is there and give them a new item

Comment: The top answer displayed in that question would work, however, my question is completely different. Which is why when I searched for an answer before posting my question; I didnt come across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead use a command such as /scoreboard to assign a label, either a score in pre-1.9 or a "tag" in 1.9+:

If you want to be able to target players after finding them, you should use a scoreboard because testfor can only target @a, @p, @e.  With a scoreboard you are not limited to testing one player or all the players.

If you use the HasItem tag then you can test if a player has the item and target them after

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HasItem] remove HasItem

/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!HasItem] add HasItem {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dirt"}]}
```

Then you can target the tag. Example:

```
/effect @a[tag=HasItem] minecraft:speed 1 3
```

You could also test to see if the payer is holding the item and then target them:

The SelectedItem compound holds a copy of the player's currently-held item.

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldingItem] remove HoldingItem

/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=!HoldingItem] add HoldingItem {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}
```

Then you can target them. Example:

```
/kill @a[tag=HoldingItem]
```

**1.8**

```
/scoreboard objectives add HasItem dummy
```

Run on a clock in presented order.

```
/scoreboard players set @a HasItem 0

/scoreboard players set @a HasItem 1 {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:dirt"}]}
```

The last command will set "HasItem" to 1 if the player has a dirt. You can then target the player based on their score.

```
/effect @a[score_HasItem_min=1] minecraft:speed 1 3
```

[How can I target a player after detecting an item in their inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259115/how-can-i-target-a-player-after-detecting-an-item-in-their-inventory)

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: So if the player has the item you are using something like /give (player) minecraft:blaze_rod?

Comment: If you've read my last comment, I meant to delete it; it was some weird bug which sort of cancelled itself out. Otherwise, ?

Comment: Yeah I read it, and noticed it was deleted. (: